# Having difficulty getting kannel to work with ssl

Tags: ssl, sms-gateway, kannel

I am having an issue getting **ssl** to work with **kannel**. I have read the userguide again and again but cannot figure it out.

The issue involves the "get" script which is held on a remote domain protected by ssl. I have copied the certs and placed them on the local kannel server. Furthermore, I have added the following code, as per the userguide, to the kannel.conf file:

```
group = core
...
ssl-server-cert-file = "filename"
ssl-server-key-file = "filename"

group = smsbox
...
sendsms-port-ssl = true
```

If anyone has any ideas or tips, please share them. Thanks.

Comment: What seems to be the issue? The "get" script returns some error? Kannel does not start? Which error the "get" script returns? Could you be more descriptive!